# if condition in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to execute for loop based on some condition depending which variable is greater.The code is this,but I am getting error ,I actually don`t know if it is legal to write short if condition in a for loop.

```
int main()
{
    int Frow=5;
    int Rowi=1;
    int i;int red=2;
    for((Rowi<Frow) ? i=Rowi : i=Frow ;(Rowi<Frow) ? i<Frow : i>Rowi;(Rowi<Frow) ? i++ : i--){
        printf("%i\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the idea is if Rowi is smaller than Frow i=Rowi; then again if Rowi is smaller i

```
for(i=Rowi;i<Frow;i++)
```

If it is the other way the for loop should be

```
for(i=Frow;i>Rowi;i--)
```

Edit :
actually my logic was wrong ,what I wanted to achieve was this

```
typedef int Bool;
#define False 0
#define True 1
int main()
{

    Bool pomalko=False;
    Bool increment=False;Bool decrement=False;
    Bool pogolqmo=False;
    int i;int red=2;
    if(Rowi<Frow){
        i=Rowi;pomalko=True;increment=True;
    }
    else if(Frow<Rowi){
        i=Rowi;pogolqmo=True;decrement=True;
    }
    for(i;(pomalko) ? i<Frow : i>Frow;(increment) ? i++ : i--){
        printf("%i\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I am getting error*  You must share that error with us!!

Comment: In your edit you declare and _not_ initialize `i`; then you initialize it to something in one part of an `if`; to something else  in the `else if`; and then you leave it as just `i` in the initialization part of the `for`. In some cases, in particular `Frow == Rowi`, `i` will be _uninitialized_ at that point. This is just wrong.

Comment: Well ,there is no chance Frow==Rowi ,because this is just short part of the code ,that you see.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-write it like this, using if statements to check how big `Rowi` and `Frow` are:

```
int main(){
    int Frow=5;
    int Rowi=1;
    int i;int red=2;



    if(Rowi < Frow){ //if rowi is less than frow, use i++
        for(i=Rowi;i<Frow;i++){
            printf("%i\n",i);
        }
    }

     else{ //else, if rowi is greater or equal to frow, use i--
        for(i=Frow;i>Rowi;i--){
            printf("%i\n",i);
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for((Rowi<Frow) ? i=Rowi : i=Frow; ...
```

in the for loop, use this:

```
for(i = (Rowi<Frow) ? Rowi : Frow; ...
```

Anyway consider using another support variable to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good style, but the actual syntax problem is that this:

```
(Rowi<Frow) ? i=Rowi : i=Frow
```

should be

```
i = (Rowi<Frow) ? Rowi : Frow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to a for loop as long as you are adding it correctly:

```
i=(Rowi<Frow) ? Rowi : Frow ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simplifying this to make it more readable. Don't try to squeeze extra functionality into your for() loop. The description you gave after your code makes more sense. Try this:

```
if(Rowi<=Frow){
    for(i=Rowi;i<Frow;i++){
        // TODO
    }
} 
else{
    for(i=Frow;i>Rowi;i--){
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's legal, but you're trying to cram some complicated logic into that for construct.

Your program would be easier to write and easier to debug if you wrote it this way:

```
int main(){
  int Frow=5;
  int Rowi=1;
  int i;
  int red=2;
  i=(Rowi<Frow)?Rowi:Frow;
  while( (Rowi<Frow && i<Frow) || (Rowi>=Frow && i>Rowi)){
    printf("%i\n",i);
    if(Rowi<Frow)
      i++;
    else
      i--;
    //Alternatively: i+=(Rowi<Frow)?1:-1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

From there, you may be able to further simplify the code:

```
if(Rowi<=Frow){
  for(i=Rowi;i<Frow;i++){
    // TODO
  }
} else {
  for(i=Frow;i>Rowi;i--){
    // TODO
  }
}
```

Remember, compact code usually does not lead to faster execution but almost always leads to slower thinking.